# Humanizer Localization Issue in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, localization, humanizer

In a Xamarin.Forms app, I calling Humanizer from the Core (.Net Standard project)
I'm using the Nugets **Humanizer.Core** and **Humanizer.Core.ru** package for Russian
And calling it
DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-3).Humanize(culture: new CultureInfo("ru-Ru"));

And always I get english
like 3 minutes ago

I tried apply:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("ru-Ru"); 
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
```

And these not infleunt on a result, I get again english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue with the workaround.

1. I removed from Nuget all Humanize packages.
2. Follow to the packages directory: C:\Users\USERNAME\.nuget\**packages**
3. Need to copy files Humanize dll's from next's folders:

- **humanizer.core**\2.8.26\lib\netstandard2.0 (**Humanizer.dll, Humanizer.xml**)
- **humanizer.core.ru**\2.8.26\lib\netstandard2.0 (copy folder "ru" with file - **ru\Humanizer.resources.dll**)

4. Into my project folder I created **CommonResources** folder.
   Then I created **Humanize** folder into CommonResources and pasted 2 files and "ru" folder to my Humanize.

[image]

5. Add references to PCL project **yourProject.csproj** file on these dll's.

```
  <ItemGroup> 
    .......
    <Reference Include="Humanizer.Core">
    <HintPath>..\..\CommonResources\Humanizer\Humanizer.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference> 
    <Reference Include="Humanizer.Core.ru">
    <HintPath>..\..\CommonResources\Humanizer\ru\Humanizer.resources.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
     ....... 
  <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="5.0.0.2012" /> 
</ItemGroup>
```

[image]

After the dll files were added I got localized text into my project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thx @polyariz, I can confirm this still works with .NET MAUI, just copy the .dlls to the Resources folder...
[image: Manually added .dlls]

and add them to the project via right-click on Dependencies and "Add Project Reference..."
[image]